# Java ArrayBlockingQueue.offer is getting blocked even it is TIMED_WAITING

Tags: java, multithreading

```
#26 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3bc8396800 nid=0x5934 waiting on condition [0x00007f3bf0ef1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000726f2cc58> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.offer(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:379)
```

The method offer(E e, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) is used here with timeout of 10 secs,but it never comes back. Does anybody know what may be the reason of this or solution for this ?

Comment: pease show you code

Comment: Here two threads are accessing the same queue. One thread is populating it using offer method and other is de-queuing it using poll method. This is seen only when thread using poll method is not there.

Answer (score 0):

As per oracle docs "offer(E e, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
Inserts the specified element at the tail of this queue, waiting up to the specified wait time for space to become available if the queue is full."

But the problem was seen when the queue was getting full. So offer method waited infinitely there.
There was 2 workaround which fixed the problem.
1. Increasing queue size
2. calling poll()

As in my case cleanup has to be performed for the object having this queue, cleanup can't be performed until this queue is not in use. So I called poll() method to unblock the offer() and then could clean without issue.
Increasing the queue size also solved the problem as it never reached to full state.